# running shell commands in php ajax

Tags: php, ajax, shell

As a Newbie: I am trying to develop a php application that runs shell commands and displays the output on the web page.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.get("snmp-cmd.php?code=myFunction", function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Execute Command</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php file:

```
<?php


$command1 = "snmpget -v 3 -u username -a SHA -A mypasswd -x DES -X mypasswd -l authPriv -IR 192.168.1.1:161 eNodeBopStatus.0";
$command = "sudo whoami";
$output1 = shell_exec($command);
$output = exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

The problem is : if I try $command = "ls -ltr", it works but if I try "whoami" or a snmp command, the Data in the alert box is not displayed.

Note: If I run the php file on console, I see output for "whoami" and snmp commands. I guess, It's just that it is not displayed in the ajax part.
I'm debugging in chrome: Network tab > Time latency displays: Pending

Please help.

Comment: with your `whoami` i think it's pending because of the sudo. try without sudo and it should - maybe - work

Comment: @atester have you tried sudo echo `whoami`

Comment: What do your error_log says?  Any errors?

Comment: @ sheplu I tried without sudo as well but it does not work

Comment: @shashi "sudo echo whoami" too, does display anything in "Data"

Answer (score 0):

Did you visudo all the commands you want to execute via PHP? for example.
`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami`